# Cannot save a string to external file on Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, writefile

Can't write my string to file on external storage. I have write and read external storage permissions in Manifest. Also added this one

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

from previous similar questions. But nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance

```
  if (isSDCARDAvailable()) {
        writeToFile(resultJson.toString());
  }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "false");
  }    


 private void writeToFile(String string){
            String filename = "routes.txt";

            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard.getPath(), filename);
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(string);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static boolean isSDCARDAvailable(){
            return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to mount or unmount external file systems. You need the permission to **access** and write to the external file system. Also, do you get any error?

Comment: This question has been answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android

Comment: Yeah, I also thought so, just saw it in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963713/3847464.    No I don't get any error. When debugging also didn't see anything noticeable,  every line is executed. But no files on sdcard whatsoever

Comment: @pVas94, answer provided there also doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't write to external storage on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963428/cant-write-to-external-storage-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this permission instead of mount and unmount, it will work. If it does not, please paste the error you are getting.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have this permission. I don't get any errors as well

Comment: Ok guys, Thanks. That was my fault. I was just looking through my sdcard with standard Windows file manager, for some reason it doesn't show this file. My devices file manager shows the file just fine

Answer (score 0):

If every lane is executed, Log the string to see if it's empty ?