# database backup works on android 4.4.2 but problem on 9

Tags: java, android

I am using this function to store database file as backup file:

```
private void saveDATABASE() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//app.myapp.com.myapplication//databases//" + Database.DATABASE_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = "backup_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WARNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

On android 4.4.2 it works successfully (database file is created with all saved data). But on android 9 it works just partially - database file is created but it does not containt the most recent database data in this file (for example some most recent entries are missing in this file, but they are in my app - looks like backed up file is older version of database). Should be there any improvement of this code for new version of android please? thanks in advance

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963713/2166337

Comment: @npk, in my case, file is written but content of file seems to be "outdated".

Comment: are you sure that the source and target files immediately after copying is different? May be the changes u made are not committed

Comment: yes, this was my idea, too. I am using the same app on both android versions but I have no idea if older android commits changes right immediately and newer android probably does not (?).